# Import Error: 'scipy.misc import imsave' on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, scipy, google-colaboratory

**Not able to use scipy.misc.imsave on Colaboratory**

```
from scipy.misc import imsave
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'imsave'

Tried to install **Pillow** and **Scipy** again on **Colab**, but the requirements are already satisfied, so **Colab** does not install these packages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html), imsave is deprecated. You can use `imageio.imwrite` instead.

In case you really need it, you can install an older scipy version.

```
!pip install -U scipy==1.2.0
```

Comment: There is no module named "imwrite" in imageio.

Comment: It is taking infinity to download.
Flash: Building wheel for scipy (setup.py) ... \

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import save_img
```

Instead of

```
from scipy.misc import imsave
```

Answer (score 1):

imsave is deprecated! imsave is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imwrite instead.

this is [detail](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html).